TeXstudio: Autocomplete for newcommands in a separate package
I created my own package where I defined several new commands with \newcommand and saved it in \texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex\local.
After I imported the package at the beginning of my file, it is recognized, as using and compiling my new commands does work perfectly.
But I have two problems:
First, although compiling, my commands are still marked red, but when I hover over them, it says "no error".
Second, and most important, there is no autocomplete for my commands, so I have to type the whole command + brackets every single time.
I have now searched for an answer for quite some time, but didn't find anything useful.
Does anybody have a solution? Thanks!

Texstudio uses .cwl files to create the autocompletion. You can create a custom one with the macros from your package. See e.g. https://texstudio-org.github.io/background.html#description-of-the-cwl-format
